# Play framework anorm DB field with Long and default null

Tags: mysql, playframework, anorm

I'm trying to create a case class and object as below

```
case class Log (
  id: Pk[Long],
  module: String,
  reference: Option[Long],
  remarks: String,
  at:  Option[Date] )

object Log {

  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("id") ~
      get[String]("module") ~
      get[Option[Long]]("reference") ~
      get[String]("remarks") ~
      get[Option[Date]]("at") map {
        case id ~ module ~ reference ~ remarks ~ at => Log(id, module, reference, remarks, at)
      }
  }
```

How to I create an object of Log with null values for reference & at, and save it?

```
 val log: Log = new Log(NotAssigned, "user", null, "DFD", null)
```

Could you please guide on what I'm doing wrong? Also, at (db column) has a default value to now [using mysql]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using scalas option class use None instead of null:

```
val log: Log = new Log(NotAssigned, "user", None, "DFD", None)
```